# What kinds of calculations have to execute for obtaining the velocity of the chemical precipitation of some salt on a thread from a water-salt mix?

Tags: quantum-espresso, computational-chemistry, ab-initio-calculations, lammps

Some salt ($\ce{NaCl}$ or another one) of $m$ grams is dissolved in some water of $V$ liters. After mixing up, the substance looks transparent or to put it more exact as a chemical solution. Then a thread of $l$ meters is placed in the substance for the chemical precipitation. The problem is to calculate the velocity of the precipitation and an on-velocity influence of a kind of matter of which the thread was made.

What kinds of calculations have to execute for reaching this purpose?
Can the Quantum Espresso or LAMMPS be engaged for this?
Or is there something else more better for this purpose?

Comment: I would say this is extremely hard to predict. In particular, knowing the composition of the thread likely does not suffice, and you have to know e.g. how smooth the surface of the thread is. You'll have to characterize the thread using some kind of microscopy in order to get this data. But this is a more difficult and expensive experiment (especially concerning the data processing of the image) than to experimentally measure the precipitation rate itself...

Comment: @wzkchem5 If we would simplify the task and take a carbon nanotube (or something that has a regularity in its building) as a thread then would the state of affairs be changed?

Comment: @SFriendly As a rule of thumb molecular dynamics directly models nanometer volumes over nanosecond durations. You'll be just fine with continuum models.